# Drush can not connect to mysql when run a Drupal in a Docker/Azure

Tags: drush

I have a website that it's running ok in Docker/Azure.

I have this configuration in my settings.php

```
$databases ['default'] ['default'] = array (
    'database' => getenv ( 'MYSQL_DATABASE' ),
    'username' => getenv ( 'MYSQL_USER' ),
    'password' => getenv ( 'MYSQL_PASSWORD' ),
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => getenv ( 'MYSQL_HOSTNAME' ),
    'port' => getenv ( 'MYSQL_PORT' ),
    'driver' => 'mysql'
);
```

When I make drush status

I get this.

```
 Drupal version   : 8.7.3                                      
 Site URI         : http://default                             
 DB driver        :                                       
 DB hostname      :                                      
 DB port          :                                        
 DB username      :                                 
 DB name          :
```

Any idea how to make that Drush get the mysql configuration options?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding `unix_socket' => '/PATH/TO/SOCKET',` ?

Comment: Hello Berramou, no the problem it's not the socket, Drush it's not able to get the enviroment variable that Docker pass to the server.

Comment: As always, turn on debugging to get some more info - `drush -d status`. The output you posted must be truncated? Update your question with more info.

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing mysql client in your docker image?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the environment variables are defined only for HTTP requests. In other words, they seem to be set in FPM, NGINX, or Apache, but not in your shell.

Try typing `echo $MYSQL_DATABASE` in your shell. If that outputs nothing, you'll have to export the environment variables first, so Drush can see them.

Comment: Yes, at the end we have export all the enviroment variables to bash_rc so Drush can get them.